# PooledRedisClientManager throws with Appharbor Redis URL

Tags: redis, servicestack, appharbor

I am trying out Redis on Appharbor in an MVC4 application. I am using the [ServiceStack C# client for Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis). Everything was working when using the `RedisClient` from `ServiceStack.Redis`. However, because I only plan to use Redis for caching, I attempted to wire up the `ICacheClient` that ServiceStack provides as a wrapper. Here is my StructureMap configuration (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching):

```
x.For<IRedisClientsManager>().Use(() => new PooledRedisClientManager(redisUrl));
x.For<ICacheClient>().Use(c => c.GetInstance<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
```

My problem is that the `PooledRedisClientManager` is throwing error, "`input string was not in a correct format`" when I use the Redis-to-Go URL provided by Appharbor. Here is what that looks like:

```
redis://redistogo-appharbor:abunchofrandomcharacters@drum.redistogo.com:9081/
```

If I replace the Redis-to-Go URL with `localhost:5051` everything works.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing a `redis://` is not any known redis convention - it must be a RedisToGo or AppHarbor convention.

ServiceStack's C# RedisClient supports standard "password@host:port" convention, e.g:

```
container.Register(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(
    "redistogo-appharbor:abunchofrandomcharacters@drum.redistogo.com:9081"
));
```

Comment: that does not work. I tried password@host:port, no success.... do u have an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
container.Register(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(
    @"abunchofrandomcharacters@drum.redistogo.com:9081"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error this works.

```
string redisUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["REDISTOGO_URL"].Replace("redis://",    "").Replace("redistogo:","").Replace("/", "");
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));
SetConfig(new HostConfig{HandlerFactoryPath = "api"});
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(redisUrl));
container.Register<IDbRepository>(r => new DbRepository(r.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));
```